# Sencha Touch filterBy the Store

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs-mvc

Code:

```
this.searchField = new Ext.form.Text({
            displayField: 'name',
            valueField: 'name',
            editable: true,
            forceSelection: true,
            triggerAction: 'all',
            emptyText: 'Search...',
            selectOnFocus: true
    });

this.searchButton = new Ext.Button({// The button press will invoke the search action
        text: 'Go',
        handler: this.searchButtonTap,
        scope: this
    });

    this.topToolbar = new Ext.Toolbar({
                   items: [
                { xtype: 'spacer' },    
                    this.searchField,
                    this.searchButton,
                    { xtype: 'spacer' },
                ]
        });

searchButtonTap: function () {

        var searchText = this.searchField.getValue();
        console.log(searchText);
        //console.log(this.myappsList.store.getCount());
        console.log(this.myappsList.store.filter('name', searchText));
        //this.myappsList.store.filter(searchText);

    },
```

in my models i have four fields:

Name, Age, Sex, Charecteristic

What i am trying over here is:

display the content of my database in a list on the page, since the list is long i wanted to search, when user writes the query in search field and presses the search button, the `searchButtonTap`  handler is invoked which tries to filter and display the list with names similar to the ones in query i also tried `filterBy` but that too did not work. Please let me know whats wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can try this way:

```js
searchButtonTap: function () {
        var searchTerm = this.searchField.getValue();
        if (searchTerm) {
            this.myappsList.store.filterBy(function(record){
            var fieldData = record.data.city.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm);
            if (fieldData > -1 ) 
                return record;
            });


        }
        else {
            this.myappsList.store.clearFilter();
            }
    },
```